# На самом деле, - что это?

Tags: фразеология, грамотная-речь

"**На самом деле**", - что это?

Из реферата: "Освоение Сибири русскими. Начало. **На самом деле**, русские знали об обширных территориях за Уралом много ранее XV века..." и т. д. Вопрос к автору реферата: а кто-то утверждал иное? С кем, собственно, с самого порога автор затеял спор?

Что же такое, это "самое" дело? Самое дно  - ниже некуда; самый край - дальше обрыв; самая вершина - выше только небо. По нынешним временам о самом трудном, полезном, неблагодарном и т.п. деле приходится слышать реже, чем **о "самом" деле**.

Кто-нибудь из знающих природу этого "фразеологизма" может раскрыть его логику и невероятную популярность?

Comment: Выражение, заменяемое следующими:
ОКАЗЫВАЕТСЯ, КАК ОКАЗАЛОСЬ, НА ДЕЛЕ ЖЕ, и т.п.

Русский язык богат на такие премудрости (тонкости).

Comment: Да, заменяемое. Теоретически. На деле - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный отрывок:

" Освоение Сибири русскими. Начало.

На самом деле, русские знали об обширных территориях за Уралом много ранее XV века. Однако внутренние политические проблемы не давали правителям обратить взор на восток. Первый военный поход в сибирские земли был предпринят Иваном III лишь в 1483 году, в результате которого были покорены манси, а вогульские княжества стали данниками Москвы. Всерьез же за восточные земли взялся Иван Грозный, да и то только к концу своего правления".

Выражение "на самом деле" имеет два значения: а) вводная конструкция, за которой следует доказательство ранее высказанной мысли; б) обстоятельство со значением "фактически, действительно".

В приведенном отрывке **следует использовать необособленное обстоятельство "на самом деле".**
Если  же мы хотим применить вводное сочетание, то надо четко обозначить мысль, которую мы собрались доказывать.

К примеру, пусть это будет тезис о том, что начало освоения Сибири - это 15 век, тогда можно сказать так: В самом деле, хотя русские знали об обширных территориях за Уралом много ранее XV века, первый военный поход в сибирские земли был предпринят Иваном III лишь в 1483 году.

Comment: Спасибо за столь развёрнутое обоснование. Отдельное - за поправку: В самом деле. 

Однако, я не смог выразить суть вопроса и уж, конечно, не имел ввиду конкретный текст. Ещё раз. Не имею ничего против "в деле", "в самом деле" или "в самОм деле", "на деле". Но не могу понять надобность употребления "на самом деле" вообще, к тому же почти всегда в начале речи, да ещё с такой зашкаливающей частотностью, которая соперничает разве что со столь же избыточными: достаточно и довольно.

И всё-таки: самое дно - ниже некуда; самый край - дальше обрыв. Что может означать "самое" дело?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не первый задаётесь этим вопросом. Его уже довольно подробно обсудили в интернетах.

> **На самом деле** — выражение, предваряющее Истину™, часто в
> последней инстанции. [...] На самом
> деле, выражение «на самом деле» давно
> стало таким же, хотя и более
> интеллигентным, словесным паразитом,
> как «типа», «реально», «по ходу», «как
> бы» и прочие сленговые словечки...

(https://lurkmore.to/на_самом_деле )